# Delphi - Excel - How to speed up operation

Tags: excel, performance, delphi

I am writing a plug-in for Excel in Delphi XE6.  I am having to "copy" rows from one sheet to another sheet.  The challenge is that my operation is taking a lot longer than I think it  should.  For example, to copy 500 rows (23 columns) from one sheet to another takes 28 seconds or so...

Part of the challenge is that I have to process row by row.  I have an array of INT, one INT per row.  The INT value tells me if I need to copy that row...

```
...for loop i ... through entire array....
...if row I am interested in...

      // Set the Original Sheet Active
      MasterOrigSheet.Select;

      // Build my row numbers
      SourceRangeCell := 'A' + IntToStr(i);
      DestRangeCell := 'A' + IntToStr(DestRowNumber);

      // Copy the row from source to destination
      MasterOrigSheet.Range[SourceRangeCell, SourceRangeCell].EntireRow.Copy
        (NewSheet.Range[DestRangeCell, DestRangeCell].EntireRow);
      Inc(DestRowNumber);
```

Is there a faster way to do this?  I am copying the entire row.  I am not using the COPY/PASTE buffer...  Any help or ideas appreciated.

Comment: The fastest way to do this is to call `Copy` exactly once. Specify the entire source in a single range and call `Copy` on it.

Comment: @@David, out of 600 rows, I might want rows 1,2,4,5,7,8,9,13,14,17... Basically I will do most of them, but I will certainly skip some/many... aka my rows are not contiguous.  I can't find anyway to define a range like this...That's the only way I can call COPY just once, correct?

Comment: Can't you select multiple rows? Same effect if in Excel its self, holding control and selecting a second range.

Comment: Or copy just all rows and delete afterwards the rows you dont want

Comment: To define a range like that, use the `Application.Union` command. It creates compound ranges, and its constituent ranges needn't be contiguous.

Comment: @Zibelas, I doubt that would bring much improvement. I strongly suspect that the major time sink in this operation is *not* the actual copying of data from one sheet to the next, but rather it's the number of COM calls being made. If I'm right, then your suggestion would only improve things when copying more than 50% of the rows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The goal is to limit the number of calls you need to make to Excel.

To that end, take advantage of the fact that the `Worksheet.Range` property accepts multiple cells in a single string. Use the union operator (comma) to describe multiple cells at once. That is, in your loop, build up a comma-separated list of the cells you want to copy. Then call `Range` to get a range reference, and use `EntireRow.Copy` on that single range.

Also, avoid repeating work that doesn't need to be done. For example, the origin sheet should remain selected throughout your loop, so you don't need to keep on telling Excel to select it on each iteration. Even though the operation has no net effect, your program still needs to go through the work of packing up the COM call and delivering it to Excel.

Comment: Rob, I like the idea, but I can't find any syntax that allows this.  I have tried MyRange := sheet.range[A5..H5 A6..H6];     MyRange := sheet.range[A5:H5 A6:H6];     MyRange := sheet.range[A5 H5 A6 H6]; and     MyRange := sheet.range.cells[A5 H5 A6 H6];    I know I can use the UNION command, but can't seem to make the union operator (space) work.

Comment: I said to build a *string*: `sheet.range['A5 A7 A9'].EntireRow` to create a range consisting of three non-adjacent rows.

Comment: But that still does NOT work.  sheet.range['A5,A6'].EntireRow is valid.  That runs fine.  If I change it to ... sheet.range['A5 A6'].EntireRow;  it compiles, but then throws a COM error at runtime.  Using SPACE between the row list is not valid syntax (as far as I can tell).  I am running Excel 2013 by the way.

Comment: I'm sorry. I must have misread something. The space operator is for intersection. The *comma* operator is for union. Use the comma.

Comment: That worked... sheet.range['A5,A7,A9'].EntireRow;   THANK YOU.  I looked in the developer docs for Excel, and could not find any reference to this syntax.  Where did you find it at?

Comment: Example number 6 [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Type-Formulas-in-Microsoft-Excel) is one source.

Comment: @user1009073 Just curious: Can you tell us your speed improvement? And don't forget to mark Rob's answer as the correct one.

Comment: The [documentation for the `Worksheet.Range` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836512.aspx): The first parameter "can include the range operator (a colon), the intersection operator (a space), or the union operator (a comma)."

Comment: Or this overview: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-formulas-HP010081865.aspx#BMusing_calculation_operators_in_formul

Comment: Thanks everyone.  As to performance improvement... when moving the MasterOrigSheet.Select OUT of the loop (which has 512 entries) time went from 28 seconds to 16.  As to putting all rows in the Sheet.Range[].EntireRow operator, there is a limit on the number of rows allowed.  50 works, 100 COM errors out... but 50 rows is basically instantaneous.

Comment: 100 should be fine. Probably a fixed upper limit on range spec text length. Using the Union function will overcome that. I think.